# These rules don't work and I don't know why

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to do a temporary redirect from one site to another.
I got this code from this site > [redirect one site to another](http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/)

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ukhorseracingtipster.com$ [OR]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ukhorseracingtipster.com$
       RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.fromthestables.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   </IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.

I've put it at the top of the .htaccess file and bottom. Doesn't make a difference.

What do I need to do to redirect one site to another

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? If you personally enabled it, did you restart apache afterward?

Comment: Is your .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Yes its enabled and has been for years. mod_rewrite is enabled and this is a 5 year old site. I restarted apache afterwards as well.

Comment: problem is I cannot tunnel into the server with Putty to run restart commands that way. Putty is just not working for some reason. It was working the last time I used it but now not even a black console box opens up.